# Anypoint Studio - Flow design - How to mark TODOs?

Tags: mule, comments, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

During the design process/implementation of flows sometimes I know that there is something that is missing. In order to make sure that I won't forget about this I am adding "TODO: the task to do" loggers.

I use these similar to do "TODO" or "FIXME" comments in java.

Is there a better way to add "TODOs" to the flows in Anypoint Studio? How to keep track of missing parts or potential improvements of our flows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add TODO comments in the flow XMLs:

> ```
> </db:template-query>
>
> <!-- TODO remember the milk -->
> <db:template-query name="Update-Employee" doc:name="Template Query">
> ```

These will be shown in the tasks view in Anypoint Studio, if you configure it properly:

1. In *preferences->General->Editor->Task Tags*, ticked the "enable searching for task tags"
2. Then to view your todo markers in Task view, if not shown goto *Window->show view->Tasks*

Answer (score 0):

Nice.
The checkbox "Enable searching for Task Tags" moved to "Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Structured Text Editors -> Task Tags" now.